# Can I assign values to this html element

Tags: jquery, tags

Can I assign a value to a html element?

https://jsfiddle.net/tgbvf3sy/16/

What I have is

```
<area shape="rectangle" coords="0,0,50,50" id="test" alt='3'/>
```

In the jquery code, I grab the 3 from the alt tag, add 1 and assign it back to alt.

```
k=parseInt(this.alt)+1;
this.alt = k
```

Click the icon to see the number counting up. I will use this in another calculation, but I also need another number for the same element. Is there a way I can assign something like alt2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use the 'attr' function on the element.

```
$(this).attr("alt2", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, beggining on 3 like your example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var altVal = $('#test').prop('alt');
   $('#test').prop('alt', parseInt(altVal)+1);
  console.log($('#test').prop('alt'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<area shape="rectangle" coords="0,0,50,50" id="test" alt='3'/>
<button>ADD</button>
```

Comment: I tried <area shape="rectangle" coords="0,0,50,50" id="test" alt='3' alt2='10'/>  and then k=$('#test').prop('alt2')  but it failed.

Comment: Will it be always int? Or may be floats as well?